SpringBoot eliminación en cascada viola la llave foránea «fk_user_id» en la tabla
Ayuda! Estoy realizando una APIRest en SpringBoot, ya implementé los métodos GET, PUT y POST pero con el DELETE estoy teniendo un inconveniente debido al parecer a las relaciones entre mis entidades.
Esta es mi entidad users:
public class Users {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id_user;

    @Column(length = 25)
    private String document;

    @Column(length = 50)
    private String firstname;

    @Column(length = 50)
    private String lastname;

    @NotBlank(message = "Please, add an username")
    @Column(length = 50)
    private String username;

    @NotBlank(message = "Please, add a password")
    @Length(min = 6)
    private String password;

    @NotBlank(message = "Please, add an email")
    private String email;

    private String phone;

    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Date creation_date;
    
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(foreignKey = @ForeignKey(name = "fk_user_rol_id"), name = "id_rol")
    private UsersRol rol;
    
    @PrePersist
    protected void onCreate(){
        creation_date = new Date();
    }
}

Esta es mi entidad Tasks
public class Tasks {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id_task;

    @NotBlank
    private String title;
    private String detail;

    @Column(length = 30)
    private String status;

    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Date start_date;

    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Date update_date;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(foreignKey = @ForeignKey(name = "fk_user_id"), name = "id_user")
    private Users id_user;
    
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(foreignKey = @ForeignKey(name = "fk_task_type_id"), name = "id_task_type")
    private TaskTypes id_task_type;

    @PrePersist
    protected void onCreate(){
        start_date = new Date();
        update_date = new Date();
    }

}

Y esta en donde relaciono que una tarea puede que la realice uno o mas usuarios asignados
public class UsersTasks {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(foreignKey = @ForeignKey(name = "fk_task_id"), name = "id_task")
    private Tasks id_task;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(foreignKey = @ForeignKey(name = "fk_user_id"), name = "id_user_assigned")
    private Users id_user_assigned;
}

El problema viene cuando intento realizar un DELETE de un user, me dice lo siguiente:

could not execute statement [ERROR: update o delete en «users» viola
la llave foránea «fk_user_id» en la tabla «users_tasks»\n  Detail: La
llave (id_user)=(2) todavía es referida desde la tabla «users_tasks».]
[delete from users where id_user=?]; SQL [delete from users where
id_user=?]; constraint [null]

Lo que quisiera es solo afectar la tabla en donde realizo el DELETE sin realizar una eliminación en cascada. Alguien me ayuda???

Lo que mencionas, dejaría registros huérfanos en tu base de datos, ¿Por qué querrías hacer eso?

Simplemente para saber como hacerlo en caso de que a futuro en esta entidad u otra se requiera

Es algo que, en una base de datos relacional, generalmente no querrás hacer y, de hecho, para prevenirlo, existe la integridad referencial.  Si quieres hacerlo, entonces no declaras ninguna regla de integridad.
